# Click inside <webview> not triggering EventListener on outer <div>

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app

In the following piece of javascript I have an event listener which is triggered by a click on `.content-container` which can be seen in the html provided.

My problem is that a click inside the content that is visible via the `<webview>` will not trigger my event listener. It makes sense that it does not trigger the click event in the app but my question would be how do I get it to trigger the click event ?

```
document.querySelector('.content-container').addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if ( event.target.classList.contains('toggle-nav') && !event.currentTarget.classList.contains('open') ) {
        event.currentTarget.classList.add('open');
    } else {
        event.currentTarget.classList.remove('open');
    }
}, false);
```

--

```
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="titlebar">
            <button class="toggle-nav">toggle</button>
            <div class="title">Toolbar</div>
            <i class="icon search">icon</i>
        </div>
        <div class="toolbar">
            <i class="icon menu">icon</i>
            <i class="icon menu">icon</i>
            <button class="toggle-content-secondary">toggle</button>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="contentareamain" class="primary">
                <webview id="foo" src="http://awebsite.com/" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"></webview>
            </div>
            <div class="secondary">
                Extra Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want your user to be able to interact with awebsite.com in the webview?

If you just want to show the contents of the site (unlikely), you could put a transparent div over it, shielding it from receiving clicks. Then a click would go to your handler.

Otherwise, awebsite.com will by default eat up any clicks, and what happens next depends on what it does with them. On one hand, you can listen to certain DOM events, such as `newwindow`, as described in the [webview documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview.html). But that hardly fits your bill. The most reliable way then would be to inject a click handler into awebsite.com using webview's `executeScript` method. Would that work for you?

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I ended up heading in the direction of of injecting a click handler in the webview portion and listening for that in the App.